# I cannot use full screen to position imagebutton

Tags: android, position, android-relativelayout, android-imagebutton

Using `RelativeLayout` and `Fragments` I cannot use full screen to position imagebutton. How I can fix this problem to have the imagebutton in the corner of screen ?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wFx6WLNF8ATtTJW0Ck7LdrNxvVSdAKdX/view?usp=sharing

My code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:background="@color/colorBackgroundBody"  >
<ImageButton 
 android:id="@+id/clear"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_margin="0dp"
 android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
 android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
 android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
 android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
 android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
 android:background="@null"
 android:clickable="true"
 android:paddingLeft="0dip"
 android:paddingRight="0dip"
 android:src="@drawable/clear3" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set these attributes for your ImageButton

```
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Now it work also without these additional setting, I don't know why

https://drive.google.com/file/d/13Bdw2DF_MjdYPJfp2HbndXXSsTzltnp2/view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/colorBackgroundBody" >


<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/clear"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20px"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:paddingLeft="0dip"
    android:paddingRight="0dip"
    android:src="@drawable/clear" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/prev"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="172px"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20px"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:paddingLeft="0dip"
    android:paddingRight="0dip"
    android:src="@drawable/prev" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/pause"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="344px"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20px"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:paddingLeft="0dip"
    android:paddingRight="0dip"
    android:src="@drawable/pause" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/play"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="516px"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20px"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:paddingLeft="0dip"
    android:paddingRight="0dip"
    android:src="@drawable/play" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/stop"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="688px"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20px"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:paddingLeft="0dip"
    android:paddingRight="0dip"
    android:src="@drawable/stop" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/next"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="860px"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20px"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:paddingLeft="0dip"
    android:paddingRight="0dip"
    android:src="@drawable/next" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollbar2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fadeScrollbars="false"
    android:scrollbarSize="15dp"
    android:scrollbarFadeDuration="0"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
    android:background="@color/colorBackgroundBody"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/playlist"
            android:background="@color/colorBackgroundBody"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp">
        </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```